# Issue in running Spark 3.3.2 with Antlr 4.10.1

Tags: apache-spark, antlr

I've upgraded a legacy application with Hibernate 6 which used Altlr4 runtime 4.10.1. It also used spark which is 3.3.2 using Antlr4 runtime version 4.8.
While running the application getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with version 3 (expected 4).
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNDeserializer.deserialize(ATNDeserializer.java:56) ~[antlr4-runtime-4.10.1.jar:4.10.1]
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNDeserializer.deserialize(ATNDeserializer.java:48) ~[antlr4-runtime-4.10.1.jar:4.10.1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseLexer.<clinit>(SqlBaseLexer.java:1603) ~[spark-catalyst_2.13-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:107) ~[spark-catalyst_2.13-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
```

On debug, I found SqlBaseLexer is generated with antlr4 4.8 version so it throws an error while running with any higher version of antlr4.
Is there a way to run Spark 3.3.2 with a higher version of Antlr4?

Comment: can you solve this problem?

Comment: Not a solution, ran into this too, but thanks for the mention of this. In my project, I could downgrade Antlr4 for the time being to make my project work.

Comment: Hi @rabejens, may I know how did you do that as I am facing the same issue also.

Comment: Spark is using the older version intrinsically. I haven’t tried it yet, but it might work if you shaded in the dependency and rewrote the package name. However since I got the error when testing, too, it might not be feasible.